# Quickest algorithm for identifying pairs in collection of string

Tags: c#, algorithm, performance

I am looking for the quickest algorithm:

**GOAL**: output the total number of pair occurrences found on a line. The individual elements may be in any order on any given line.

INPUT:

```
a;b;c;d
a;e;f;g
a;b;f;h
```

OUTPUT

```
a;b = 2
a;c = 1
a;d = 1
a;e = 1
a;f = 2
a;g = 1
b;c = 1
b;d = 1
```

I am programming in C#, I've got a nested for loop adding do a common dictionary of type  where string is like a;b and when an occurrence is found it adds to the existing int tally or adds a new one at tally = 0.

Note this:

```
a;b = 1
b;a = 1
```

Should be reduced to this:

```
a;b = 1
```

I am open to using other languages, the output is in a plain text file which I feed into Gephi visualization tool.

Bonus: Very interested to know the name of this particular algorithm if it's out there. Pretty sure it is.

```
String[] data = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\input.txt");
Dictionary<string, int> ress = new Dictionary<string, int>();

foreach (var line in data)
{
    string[] outStrings = line.Split(';');

    for (int i = 0; i < outStrings.Count(); i++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < outStrings.Count(); y++)
        {
            if (outStrings[i] != outStrings[y])
            {
                try
                {
                    if (ress.Any(x => x.Key == outStrings[i] + ";" + outStrings[y]))
                    {
                        ress[outStrings[i] + ";" + outStrings[y]] += 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ress.Add(outStrings[i] + ";" + outStrings[y], 0);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {

                }
            }
        }
    }
}

foreach (var val in ress)
{
    Console.WriteLine(val.Key + "----" + val.Value);
}
```

Comment: I just posted the code that is currently running on my laptop :-)

Comment: This looks like [association rule learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_rule_learning), although without the assumption that you only care about associations with more than a certain threshold. Like if you were only interested in pairs that appeared together more than, say 2 times. The assumption can buy you some efficiency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@mrmcgreg, finally after changing the implementation to the [ECLAT algorythm](https://www.slideshare.net/deepa15/eclat-37310304) everything runs in seconds instead of hours.

Basically for each unique tag, keep track of the LINE NUMBERS where those tags are found, and simply intersect the pair of list of numbers by combination pairs to get the count.

```
 Dictionary<string, List<int>> uniqueTagList = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>();


            foreach (var uniqueTag in uniquetags)
            {
                List<int> lineNumbers = new List<int>();
                foreach (var item in data.Select((value, i) => new { i, value }))
                {
                    var value = item.value;
                    var index = item.i;

                    //split data into tags
                    var tags = item.ToString().Split(new[] { ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

                    foreach (var tag in tags)
                    {
                        if (uniqueTag == tag)
                        {
                            lineNumbers.Add(index);
                        }
                    } 
                }

                //remove all having support threshold.
                if (lineNumbers.Count > 5)
                {
                    uniqueTagList.Add(uniqueTag, lineNumbers);
                }  
            }
```

Answer (score 3):

I think your inner loop should start with `i + 1` instead of starting back at `0` again, and the outer loop should only run until `Length - 1`, since the last item will be compared on the inner loop. Also, when you add a new item, you should add the value `1`, not `0` (since the whole reason we're adding it is because we found one).

You can also just store the key into a string once instead of doing multiple concatenations during your comparison and assignment, and you can use the `ContainsKey` method to determine if a key exists already.

Also, you might want to consider avoiding empty `catch` blocks unless you're really certain that you don't care if or what went wrong. If I'm expecting an exception and know how to handle it, then I catch that exception, otherwise I'll just let it bubble up the stack.

Here's one way you could modify your code to find all pairs and their counts:

**Update**

I added a check to ensure that the "pair" key is always sorted, so that "b;a" becomes "a;b". This wasn't an issue in your sample data, but I extended the data to include lines like `b;a;a;b;a;b;a;`. Also I added `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` to the `Split` method to handle cases where a line begins or ends with a `;` (otherwise the null value resulted in a pair like `";a"`).

```
private static void Main()
{
    var data = File.ReadAllLines(@"f:\public\temp\temp.txt");
    var pairCount = new Dictionary<string, int>();

    foreach (var line in data)
    {
        var lineItems = line.Split(new[] {';'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        for (var outer = 0; outer < lineItems.Length - 1; outer++)
        {
            for (var inner = outer + 1; inner < lineItems.Length; inner++)
            {
                var outerComparedToInner = string.Compare(lineItems[outer], 
                    lineItems[inner], StringComparison.Ordinal);

                // If both items are the same character, ignore them and keep looping
                if (outerComparedToInner == 0) continue;

                // Create the pair such that the lower of the two 
                // values is first, so that "b;a" becomes "a;b"
                var thisPair = outerComparedToInner < 0
                    ? $"{lineItems[outer]};{lineItems[inner]}"
                    : $"{lineItems[inner]};{lineItems[outer]}";

                if (pairCount.ContainsKey(thisPair))
                {
                    pairCount[thisPair]++;
                }
                else
                {
                    pairCount.Add(thisPair, 1);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Pair\tCount\n----\t-----");

    foreach (var val in pairCount.OrderBy(i => i.Key))
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{val.Key}\t{val.Value}");
    }

    Console.Write("\nDone!\nPress any key to exit...");
    Console.ReadKey();

}
```

**Output**

Given a file containing your sample data, the output is:

[image]

Comment: I need to learn my lesson from this. LINQ is just slow. I'm imagining it's going to have some super-awesome behind-the-scenes optimization. It doesn't. Once my LINQ solution proved 100x slower I gave up and started trying to tweak your answer to make it faster. Anything and everything made it slower.

Comment: I guess sometimes the "old fashioned" loops are the fastest. I'm still convinced that I missed some optimization, though, so I'm glad you were trying! It's the best way to learn. And I dislike the key generation code too. Even if it's slower, some custom sort Linq thing would look better. :)

Comment: Thanks for this, very helpful. Any ideas on what the name of the algo might be? Wondering if there is a better way in general because I have a high volume of data.

Comment: No, I'm not sure. [This page](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26050/Permutations-Combinations-and-Variations-using-C-G) describes permutations and combinations, and may help.